# iPhone: Memory used by images is not freed

Tags: iphone, memory, uiimageview, memory-management

I have this code below that loads images from the web.
Those images are shown after clicking on a table cell, and they are reloaded every time the table cell is clicked.
The point is that analyzing the memory allocation with "Instruments", when I go back from the detail view to the table, the memory occupied from the images is not freed.

**Does anyone have any suggestion?** 
I, of course, do all the release of the case... but it seems to don't help.

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    UIImage *img = nil;
    NSString *myurl = [IMG_SERVER_URL stringByAppendingString: tmp_link.url];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    NSData *imageData = nil;
    if(myurl!=nil){
        imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myurl] options:nil error:&error];
        if (error == 0) {
            img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        }
    }
    [imageData release]; imageData = nil;
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(targetWidth*i, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight)]; 
    imageView.image = img; 
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [img release];
    [....some code....]
    [imageView release];
```

Comment: I have added a few more lines of the code, which make sense, thanks for having spotted out a missing useful part.

Answer (score 2):

I think "imageView.image = img" increases the reference count on the image object. If I'm right the allocated memory will not get freed as long as you don't release the imageView.

Comment: I do release imageView later in the code already.... I have update the code snippet again, and thanks anyway for the suggestion!